# ios architecture versions - same code

Tags: ios, binaryfiles, arm64, armv7

Are different iOS architecture binary files the same overall code, or can they be different.

If I was to check certain things on these binaries, e.g PIE, ARC, or strings such as memcpy etc. Do I need to check both thin binaries for the same things, or are they the same just with different memory addresses?

e.g `a fat binary consisting of armv7 and arm64, if the armv7 binary has PIE enabled, so will the arm64?`

`if the armv7 binary uses strcpy, the arm64 binary will also use strcpy?`

Example for further clarification: Both binaries contain the same findings, which means as below in TLDR? Same code, just compiled differently per arch.

```
armv7
0x001e7e44   665 _memcpy
0x001e7ea4   770 _strlen
0x001e7eac   772 _strncpy
0x001e85b4   665 _memcpy

arm64
0x00000001001be7f0   645 _memcpy
0x00000001001be904   746 _strlen
0x00000001001be91c   748 _strncpy
0x0000000100220f18   645 _memcpy
```

TLDR; are 2 iOS binaries the same code, just compiled differently depending on the architecture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fat binaries contain multiple independent Mach-O files, which don't need to have anything in common at all.

When compiling binaries for just one platform, that fact hardly ever becomes apparent, but when building a cross-platform binary (common for some research tools to run both on macOS and jailbroken iDevices), there's not really any way around doing it manually:

```
gcc -o program.macos program.c
xcrun -sdk iphoneos gcc -arch armv7 -arch arm64 -o program.ios program.c
lipo -create -output program program.macos program.ios
```

Now, normally multiple slices of a fat Mach-O contain the same codebase compiled for different architectures - after all, that's the intended use. That is no requirement however, as you can [staple entirely different object files together](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45182645) (disclaimer: answer by me). But as I've written in that post, doing that is of very limited use, since you have no control over the slice that is chosen.

Subtle differences are quite common though, and can arise from e.g. C code like this:

```
void some_function(void)
{
#if __LP64__
    // do something
#else
    // do something else
#endif
}
```

Examples I know include use of the (officially forbidden) IOKit framework, where the `io_*` functions are exported on 32-bit but not on 64-bit, which allowed simple imports on the former but demanded homebrew `dlsym()`-style scanning code on the latter.

In conclusion:

Are the slices of a different Mach-O usually compiled from the same code base? **Yes**.
Should they be? **Yes**.
Is that in any way guaranteed? **No**.

Comment: Ok, so even tho they can be stapled together, are they usually? Every iOS app I've looked at and checked for my examples above, pie, stack smashing, arc etc, both MAch-O files are the same... would I ever come across any differences, do I still need to check both armv7 and arm64?

Comment: we're also talking about iOS apps only here, not macOS apps

Comment: Well, what exactly do you wanna _check_? Ultimately, anything regarding the contents of Mach-O's is 100% up to the author.

Comment: the things in the OP, binary checks, strings, insecure functions use of other functions found via grep.

Comment: Updated my answer.